# Are i.i.d. random variables with infinite expectation uncorrelated?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, law-of-large-numbers

If I have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$, with $\mathbb{E}[X_i^+] = \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_i^-] < \infty$, where $X_i^+ = \max(X_i, 0)$ and $X_i^- = \max(-X_i, 0)$ can I say that they are uncorrelated?

Because I have $$cov(X_i,X_j) = \mathbb{E}(X_iX_j) - \mathbb{E}(X_i)\mathbb{E}(X_j) = 0$$ by independence, but since my expectations are infinite I get  $$cov(X_i,X_j) = \infty - \infty$$ which is undefined.

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: The definition of correlation requires the second moments to exist. If they do not exist, you can't define the correlation coefficient. As such in your case, I would say talking about correlation is not meaningful.

Comment: As stated, $X_i^+=-X_i^-$. Did you perhaps mean $X_i^- = \min(X_i, 0)$ or $X_i^- = \max(-X_i, 0)$?

Answer (score 3):

Covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is defined only when $X$ and $Y$ have finite variance.

Comment: Not true; e.g., cov(X,Y)=0 when X, Y i.i.d. ~ Student's t with d.f.=2, or Pareto with shape parameter = 2. These have infinite variance but finite expectation.